# Is there a difference between 'steigen' and 'steigern'?

Tags: synonym

Are 'steigen' and 'steigern' alternative spellings, or is there some difference in meaning?

Comment: "steigern" is the so-called [Kausativum](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Kausativ) of "steigen". So "steigen"="go up", "steigern"="make go up".

Comment: @Chris...why not make that an answer

Comment: @Emanuel: There are enough answers that give essentially the same answer as I would do. I only wanted to provide a technical term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An aspect not yet mentioned: *steigern" (increase somthing) is transitive, so you necessarily have to specify, what to increase. *Steigen" as in "Die Benzinpreise steigen" (the fuel prices increase) is perfectly happy without additional specification.

Answer (score 7):

They are two totally separate verbs. *Steigen* means to rise, climb, ascend, soar, etc. whereas *steige**r**n* means to raise, boost, augment etc.

Answer (score 3):

**1. steigen (Verb)**
The word "steigen" is often used to describe a physical activity for climbing up somewhere.

For example: *Den Berg besteigen.*

However, there are several other possible usages for different scenarios.

**2. steigern (Verb)**
The most common usage for this Verb is in the sense of increasing or enhancing something.
For example: *Den Umsatz eines Unternehmens steigern.* or *Der Sportler steigert das Tempo.*

There are other possible usages.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Why are you using a completely different word ("besteigen") in an example to show the meaning of "steigen"? Even if the words are related, they do not necessarily have a related meaning, see for example "sitzen" and "besitzen".

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks for the hint. I intended to write: "Ich steige den Berg hinauf."

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not equal in meaning. Off the top of the head I cannot come up with an example where you can replace one for the other without changing the meaning. I'm sure there are some examples, though, since the two words have a tiny overlap. Sometimes you get a similar meaning with just a subtle difference:

> Die Gehälter steigern: the act of increasing the salaries
>   Die Gehälter steigen: the fact that salaries increase

*Steigern* in general mean: to improve, to get better/more/higher.
*Steigen*, in contrast, mean: to climb, to get on a higher level.

So, the only overlap is "to get higher" which is covered by the "salary"-example.